# C++ Stack class implementation

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, stack

I'm starting learning C++ so I decided to try to implement a class able to store numeric values.
And to add a little more challenge, I decided to make it **sorted**: The elements of the stack have to be sorted in ascending order from the top to the bottom.
I decided to use NaN to represent an empty stack.

So here's the hpp file:

```
#ifndef MYMSS2_RENAME_ME_HPP
#define MYMSS2_RENAME_ME_H
class mySortedStack{
    public:
        double info;
        mySortedStack * next;

        mySortedStack();
        mySortedStack(double a);
        mySortedStack(const mySortedStack& a);
        ~mySortedStack();

        double top();
        double pop();
        void push(double a);

        int len();

};
#endif
```

and here's the cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myMSS2_RENAME_ME.hpp"
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

mySortedStack::mySortedStack(){
    //cout<<"Inside empty constuctor"<<endl;
    info=NAN;
    next=NULL;
    //cout<<"Leaving empty constuctor"<<endl;
}

mySortedStack::mySortedStack(double a){
    //cout<<"Inside normal constructor"<<endl;
    info=a;
    next=NULL;
    //cout<<"Leaving normal constuctor"<<endl;
}

mySortedStack::mySortedStack(const mySortedStack& a){//this should be able to do deepcopies
    //cout<<"Inside copy constructor"<<endl;
    info=double(a.info);
    next=new mySortedStack;
    next=a.next;
    //cout<<"Leaving copy constuctor"<<endl;
}

mySortedStack::~mySortedStack(){
    //cout<<"Inside destructor"<<endl;
    delete this;
}

double mySortedStack::top(){
    return info;
}

void mySortedStack::pop(){
    double retVal;
    mySortedStack *tempStack = this->next;
    retVal = info;
    info = tempStack->info;
    next = tempStack->next;
    tempStack->next = NULL;
    delete tempStack;
    return retVal;
}

void mySortedStack::push(double a){
    //cout<<"Pushing!"<<endl;
    if (isnan(info)){//if stack is empty
        info=a;
    }
    else{
        mySortedStack *pushed=new mySortedStack();
        if(info>a){//if the pushed element will be placed at the top
            pushed->info=info;
            pushed->next=next;
            info=a;
            next=pushed;

        }else{//else
            mySortedStack *currentNode=this;
            while(currentNode->next->info<a){
                currentNode=currentNode->next;
            }
            mySortedStack *pushed=new mySortedStack();
            pushed->info=a;
            pushed->next=currentNode->next;
            currentNode->next=pushed;
        }

    }
}



int mySortedStack::len(){
    int i=1;
    mySortedStack currentNode=*this;
    if (isnan(info)){
        return 0;
    }
    while (currentNode.next!=NULL){
        i+=1;
        currentNode=*currentNode.next;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This compiles fine (I'm using Dev C++ on Windows 8).

So I tried to run a few tests by adding a `main` function in the cpp file:

```
int main(){
    mySortedStack mss0;
    mySortedStack mss1(7);
    mySortedStack mss2=mss1;
    mss1.info=6;
    cout<<mss1.info<<' '<<mss2.info<<endl;//copy constructor seems to work! output is '6 7'

    system("PAUSE");

    mss1.push(4);
    mss1.push(5);

    //the next piece of code is supposed to show the whole stack
    bool flag=true;
    mySortedStack inspected=mss1;
    while(flag){
        cout<<inspected.info<<endl;
        if(inspected.next==NULL){
            flag=false;
            cout<<"NULL found!"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            inspected=*inspected.next;
        }
    }
    //seems correct. Output is:
    //'4
    //5
    //6
    //NULL found!'
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Aaaannd here it comes! Segmentation fault!(Exact error message: Program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault) It seems to happen just before the `return 0`.
After adding some `cout<<`, it seems that the problem resides in my destructor (infinite loop). Since I have no idea about which call of the destructor makes this, I neither have a clue if the problem is due to the destructor itself or the way I manipulate the pointers in a class method or anywhere else. I tried to draw on paper what happens inside of each of my methods and everything seems fine.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Dont do "delete this" in your constructor.

Comment: @tomasbasahm Destructor. But yes, don't do it.

Comment: Yes, destructor. Good catch

Comment: `I'm starting learning C++ so I decided to try to implement a class able to store numeric values`  To be honest with you, this type of exercise should be attempted by intermediate to advanced C++ programmers, not beginners.  Your class doesn't follow the "rule of 3", i.e. the copy constructor is buggy, you have no assignment operator, and the destructor has been commented on already as to what is wrong.  Even with the destructor "fixes", your class is easily breakable with a 2 or 3 line main() program.

Comment: In addition, what you've coded is more like a `singly linked list` than a stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mySortedStack::~mySortedStack(){
    //cout<<"Inside destructor"<<endl;
    delete this; // Uuuh ?
}
```

... I don't really know what to add to this answer.

**Edit :** In fact, I found a little something :

```
mySortedStack::mySortedStack(const mySortedStack& a){
    // ...
    next=new mySortedStack; // Hello brand new object !
    next=a.next; // Goodbye leaked object !
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aha! In complement with @StAlphonzo answer, now I understand. I fixed it by replacing `this` with `next`. Now the destructor deletes each element of the stack one after the other. Also, thanks for pointing out   that mistake in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Right, but to be specific, by calling 'delete this' you are trying to delete the current object which contains the desctructor. Delete calls the desctructor, which calls delete, etc, thus the loop.

The destructor is there so you can free any memory your class is allocated. That way when someone calls delete mySortedStackInstance ( of whatever it's called ), your class won't leak memory.

I figured I should just add that so you didn't have more confusion over what the destructor in your class is actually for.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation comes from this line

```
   mySortedStack inspected=mss1;
```

You have to write proper copy constructor.

There are other memory issues in your code:

mySorted stack is committing suicide. It is a bad style.

```
mySortedStack::~mySortedStack(){
    //cout<<"Inside destructor"<<endl;
    delete this;
}
```

Your destructor should look like this

```
mySortedStack::~mySortedStack(){
    //cout<<"Inside destructor"<<endl;
    delete this->mySortedStack;
}
```

Another lack of style are names: a class and a memeber are sharing the same name. It is difficult to read.